# What determines search order in sqlite join?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables:

```
books: 
 id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
 author TEXT,
 title TEXT
```

and

```
favoriteBooks:
 id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
 FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES books(id)
```

I am trying to see if an author exists in favorite books.

The following statment works, but is slow if favoriteBooks has a small number of rows and fast if there are a large number. I think its because I am searching through every row in books and seeing if it is in favoriteBooks instead of going through each favoriteBook and checking the author.

How can I fix this?

```
SELECT EXISTS (
SELECT 1 FROM books b 
INNER JOIN favoriteBooks f ON b.id = f.id 
AND author="Some Author" LIMIT 1);
```

thanks!

Comment: You heard about indexes?

Comment: I have an index on id in books.  Do I need to link that to favoriteBooks in some way?

Comment: Add indexes `create index somename ON books( author )` and also `create index somename2 ON favoriteBooks( id )`

Comment: @krokodilko: the second index is already there - it is a primary key

Comment: thank you both! I added indexes on all of the relevant columns in my code and the speed increase is huge!  They make a huge difference.  I understand that they can slow down updates but I won't need to do that often.  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM books b INNER JOIN
                    favoriteBooks f
                    ON b.id = f.id AND author = 'Some Author'
               LIMIT 1
              );
```

is one way to write the logic.  Note that the `LIMIT` is unnecessary.  The `EXISTS` takes care of that.

You want an index on `books(author, id)`:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_books_author_id ON books(author, id);
```

Note that there are essentially two ways to process this data.  Go through all the books that have the specified author *and* then see which are favorite books.  Or, go through all the favorite books and see which have the specified author.

Your question suggests that the number of favorite books can grow arbitrarily large, so the first method is better.

Also, note that a book can have multiple authors, but your question doesn't seem to take that into account.

Comment: _Note that there are essentially two ways to process this data. Go through all the books that have the specified author and then see which are favorite books. Or, go through all the favorite books and see which have the specified author._  How do you change which on of these is done?   Also what is different about your select statement from mine?

Comment: @phimath . . . The `SELECT` statement is your statement, formatted so I can read it.  You can't really control how the optimizer creates the execution plan.  You can give it the tools to choose the best plan -- and those tools include having appropriate indexes.